# What is the best way to get facebook's complete newsfeed for 24h?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What is the best practice of getting a facebook user's newsfeed?
For example - get the last 24h worth of news.

I've looked at both the Graph API and FQL. They both provide the functionality of getting the user's feed (/me/home), however both seem to return different result sets for the same logical query and none seems to return the complete set of news items. I wonder if that's by design.

I've experimented with different time scopes, so for example in FQL if I want to get the past 24h, a simple solution is to query for the past 24h . But this does not return all the posts in that scope. So the next step is to send 24 queries, each for a time window of 1h. That would return more items, but this is also incomplete. Similarly, sending in blocks of 4h returns yet a different number of items. Surprisingly, sending 6 queries or 4h window returns more results than sending 24 queries of 1h window. Of course these are empiric results of several tests I made, but do not necessarily describe the complete behavior of the API.

Using the graph API also does not return the complete set of items from the user's feed.

I have seen folks on SO ask questions revolving this topic but I hadn't been able to find an answer (and so I hope there is one...)

Facebook describes the Realtime API as being more reliable, so one would think that using the realtime API is the robust approach, storing the data in my own DB and building the user's feed as we go, only that the problem is that the realtime API does work for certain data items, but it is not enabled for the user's home feed (user.feed is included in the realtime API but it's something else) so this approach also seems impossible.

What is, then the best practice for getting a complete listing of user's newsfeed items in the scope of, say - 24h, or maybe 48h? If that's impossible - by design, or by business cause, then what is the closest thing that can be achieved?

I don't mind using things such as the realtime API to build this data in my own DB if that was at all possible. (of course I'll have to handle scaling one day, but until then, I first have to have the functionality working...)

I've seen a few related questions on stackoverflow but none that answers this, so if you do find one, feel free to mark mine as a dup.

Comment: A minor  tip for you - consider using fql not graph api, because the last one is very slow...

Comment: @Elmor I've seen test that go both ways (sometimes the graph is slower, sometimes fql is slower)...

Comment: hmmm i didn't know that fql could be slower! thanks for that knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook rarely ever returns all items from a user's news feed. This is by design. There is a note in the Graph API documentation that states that `/me/home` returns something different than what is in a user's newsfeed and this is by design.

Any user who has blocked app access in their privacy settings will never have their data returned by the API, but are visible on the front end. There is no way to tell what is being filtered and why. There is a blog post on the developer's blog that explains how this filtering works.

The best you can do is ask for something like `/me/home?since=yesterday&until=today&limit=1000`.